# "The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig' threw an exception"

Tags: exception, servicestack, sitefinity-6.x

Initialization failed after upgrading Sitefinity project with **"The type initializer for `ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig` threw an exception"**

Comment: Which programming language did you use? Any source code (http://stackoverflow.com/help)?

Comment: Could be a licensing issue, I'd check with Sitefinity support to ensure your license keys are correctly registered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We also have upgraded a Sitefinity project from 7.0 to 8.2. This same error message was being shown after the upgrade.

The type initializer for 'ServiceStack.Text.JsConfig' threw an exception.

To solve this we have followed the instructions on this page: http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/knowledge-base/details/service-stack-license-error-after-upgrade-to-version-8.1.

**EDIT**

As the link above no longer working as expected:

https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/ServiceStack-Text-JsConfig-error-while-upgrading-to-Sitefinity-8-2?q=service-stack-license-error-after-upgrade-to-version-8.1

> Cause:
>   An expired ServiceStack license key is present in the web.config file.
>
> Resolution: remove the offending key from `appSettings`

Comment: Thank you Mendreres, your solution has helped us resolve the issue.

Comment: the kb is no longer available for public

Answer (score 1):

To prevent this, first update your "old" license and then start the upgrading process with the new license. Licenses can be downloaded in the admin panel.

If you've already upgraded and this exception is thrown, just remove the service stack license key in your web.config as mentioned in the previous link. ( ).

I am just adding it here, to keep everything on stackoverflow. Links on Telerik / Sitefinity often dissapear or are changed (without redirects). That's why ths page probably doesn't show up in Google.